# How to get the active package path in eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Im not sure whether it is the right question because i m not able to get the absolute path of the folder which i have selected in eclipse.

The following is the code i wrote , can anyone tell me what is missing ?

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        if (window != null)
        {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) window.getSelectionService().getSelection();
            Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
            if (firstElement instanceof IAdaptable)

            {   
                IFolder folder = (IFolder)((IAdaptable)firstElement).getAdapter(IFolder.class);
                IPath path = folder.getLocation();
                System.out.println(path);
            }
        }
```

thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make your `path` to an absolute path using [IPath#makeAbsolute()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath.html#makeAbsolute%28%29). You can also transform it to an File using [IPath#toFile()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath.html#toFile%28%29) and then make it absolute (File#getAbsolutePath()).
So in your sample you could write:

```
IPath path = folder.getLocation();
System.out.println("Absolute Path:     "+path.makeAbsolute());
System.out.println("Absolute FilePath: "+path.toFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the solution........
In the above code ,when i debugged it , the IFolder was coming null.

Tried a different way and it worked .

```
public void run(IAction action) {
    ISelection sel=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().getSelection();
    IFolder folder=(IFolder) extractSelection(sel);
    IPath path=folder.getLocation();
    System.out.println("********************Folder Path"+path);

    }


 public IResource extractSelection(ISelection sel) {
     if (!(sel instanceof IStructuredSelection))
        return null;
     IStructuredSelection ss = (IStructuredSelection) sel;
     Object element = ss.getFirstElement();
     if (element instanceof IResource)
        return (IResource) element;
     if (!(element instanceof IAdaptable))
        return null;
     IAdaptable adaptable = (IAdaptable)element;
     Object adapter = adaptable.getAdapter(IResource.class);
     return (IResource) adapter;
  }
```