# How to get selected file name and its package path in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to get the file name and its package path in eclipse when right click menu is clicked.

Action class is implemented `IObjectActionDelegate`

Run method is as follows,

```
public void run(IAction action)
{
  ISelection sel = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().getSelection();
  if (!(sel instanceof IStructuredSelection))
                return null;
  }
  IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) sel ;
  Object obj = selection.getFirstElement();
  IFile file = (IFile) Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(obj, IFile.class);
```

But the "sel" variable is not a instance of IStructuredSelection. Therefore it return null.

I have gone through following link,
[How to get the active package path in eclipse workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145471/how-to-get-the-active-package-path-in-eclipse-workspace)

But no result.

Comment: When are you running this code?

Comment: @greg-449 Once user clicked on the right click menu.

Comment: What is the actual type of `sel`?

Comment: Right click where? On a view, an editor, ....?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann sel type is org.eclipse.jface.text.TextSelection

Comment: @greg-449 Right click on the editor.

Comment: A common pattern is to first obtain the selected file from the active editor input (if any). Only if there is no active editor, the selection provider is queried.

Comment: Furthermore, some JDT model elements do not directly adapt to `IFile`. Therefore, you may need to (additionally) query for a `ResourceMapping`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show should work for a selection in a view, but if you are dealing with an editor you need to do things a different way.

Something like:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();

IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();

IFile file = (IFile)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(input, IFile.class);
```